# Does using lazy evaluation when inserting into a ConcurrentDictionary prevent the requested value from being calculated multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net

In his book *Concurrency in .NET*, Riccardo Terrell provides two versions of a Memoize function (below) and claims that the second function performs better than the first because it avoids duplicate cache item initialization while also being thread safe.

My question is - Isn't it possible that the second version still leads to duplicate cache item initialization?

For each key/value pair added to the dictionary a *new* Lazy instance is initialized and returned, meaning that X threads could potentially lead to X Lazy types being initialized, ultimately leading to X invocations of *func(a)*, which is exactly what happens in the first version of the function?  From what I can see, it looks like version two behaves exactly the same as version one.

**Version 1**

```
public Func<T, R> MemoizeThreadSafe<T, R>(Func<T, R> func) where T : IComparable
{
  ConcurrentDictionary<T, R> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, R>();   ①  
  return arg => cache.GetOrAdd(arg, a => func(a));
}
```

**Version 2**

```
static Func<T, R> MemoizeLazyThreadSafe<T, R>(Func<T, R> func) where T : IComparable
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<T, Lazy<R>> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, Lazy<R>>();   ①  
    return arg => cache.GetOrAdd(arg, a => new Lazy<R>(() => func(a))).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetOrAdd` will always return the same value. Two threads may race to create a `Lazy<R>` for the same argument value, but they'll both end up with a reference to only *one* of them. They'll both in turn call `Value` on it and it will do its own initialization once. It's only the call to `Value` that forces this initialization to occur, and it's only then that `func(a)` is invoked.

The other `Lazy<R>` will be abandoned and will eventually be GCed<sup>1</sup> without ever being asked to initialize its value.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming the GC runs at all in the future, you're not running with a null GC, etc.

Comment: great, thank you. It didn't occur to me that both ```Lazy<R>``` would be created but only the value of one would be accessed, thereby never initializing the value contained in the other.